# Is a question with a time-dependent answer a good use of the FAQ feature?

Tags: discussion

We have a very old question, [How many stablised qubits have been achieved in Quantum Computing?], from 2011.

We also have a much more recent question, [Quantum computing records (entangled qubits)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102447/quantum-computing-records-entangled-qubits), from this past March.

On the one hand, these are basically asking the same question. But the answer posted and accepted for the earlier question obviously isn't relevant for the second question. The most obvious thing I can think of is to have one definitive question about qubit records, and add answers periodically that update the record (using some phrasing like "As of June 2014, the record is --").

Is this an appropriate use of the FAQ feature? If we applied that idea here, would we need to make everything Community Wiki? And how would we go about updating the accepted answer? (is that even possible?)

Or is there just a much easier solution to this problem?

I can imagine several questions that would be subject to a similar difficulty.

Comment: Essentially the same proposal, I think: [State-of-the-art tag?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/state-of-the-art-tag) (not well received, rather rightly).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, thanks for finding that. My searching did not catch your previous question. I agree that this is a dupe.